# How to create the index on MUL key in Mysql?

Tags: mysql

We need to create the index on `"source path" column`, which is already in `MUL - Key`. For Example it have `/src/com/Vendor/DTP/Emp/Grd1/Sal/2016/Jan/31-01/Joseph` and we need to search like `'%Sal/2016/Jan%'` it have almost 10 Million records.
Please suggest any idea for performance improvement.

```
    | Field      | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Id         | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | Name       | char(35) | NO   |     |         |                |
    | Country    | char(3)  | NO   | UNI |         |                |
    | source Path| char(20) | YES  | MUL |         |                |
    | Population | int(11)  | NO   |     | 0       |
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, a search that starts with `%` cannot use an index (it has not much to do with being in a composite index).

You have some options though:

- The values in your path seem to have actual meaning. The ideal solution would be to use the meta-data, e.g. the month, name, whatever "SAL" stands for, and store it in their own columns or an attribute table, and then query for that meta-data instead. This is obviously only possible in very specific cases where you have the required meta-data for every path, so it is probably not an option here.
- You can add a "search table" (e.g. `(id, subpath)`) that contains all subpaths of your source path, e.g.

  ```
  '/src/com/Vendor/DTP/Emp/Grd1/Sal/2016/Jan/31-01/Joseph'
  '/com/Vendor/DTP/Emp/Grd1/Sal/2016/Jan/31-01/Joseph'
  '/Vendor/DTP/Emp/Grd1/Sal/2016/Jan/31-01/Joseph'
  ...
  '/Sal/2016/Jan/31-01/Joseph'
  ...
  '/31-01/Joseph'
  '/Joseph'
  ```

  so 11 rows in your example. It's now possible to use an index on that, e.g. in

  ```
  ... 
  where exists 
   (select * from subpaths s
    where s.subpath like '/Sal/2016/Jan%' and s.id = outerquery.id)
  ```

  This relies on knowing the start of your search term. If `Sal` in your example `%Sal/2016/Jan` should actually include word endings, e.g. `/NoSal/2016/Jan`, you would have to modify your input term to remove the first word, so `%Sal/2016/Jan%` would require you to search for `/2016/Jan%` (with an index) and then recheck the resultset afterwards if it also fits `%Sal/2016/Jan%` (see the fulltext option for an example, it has the same "problem" to only look for the beginning of words).

  You will have to maintain the search table, which is usually done in a trigger (update the subpath table when you insert, update or delete values in your original table).

  Since this is a new table, you cannot combine it (directly) with another index, to e.g. optimize `where country = 'A' and subpath like 'Sal/2016/Jan%'` if `country = 'A'` would already get rid of 99.99% of the rows. You may have to check `explain` for your query if MySQL actually uses the index (because the optimizer can try something different) and then maybe reorganize your query (e.g. use a `join` or `force index`).
- You can use a [fulltext search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html). From the userinput, you would have to generate a query like

  ```
  select * from 
    (select * from table 
     where match(`source Path`) against ('+SAL +2016 +Jan' in boolean mode)) subquery
  where `source path` like '%Sal/2016/Jan%'
  ```

  The fulltext search will not care about the order of the words, so you have to recheck the resultset if it actually is the correct path, but the fulltext search will use the (fulltext) index to speed it up. It will only look for the beginning of words, so similar to the "search table" option, if `Sal` can be the end of the word, you have to remove it from the fulltext search. By default, only words with at least 3 or 4 letters (depending on your engine) will be added to the index, so you have to set the value of either [ft_min_word_len](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len) or [innodb_ft_min_token_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_ft_min_token_size) to whatever fits your requirements.

The search table approach is probably the most convenient solution, as it can be used very similar to your current search: you can add the userinput directly in one place (without having to interpret it to create the `against (...)` expression) and you can also use it easily in other situations (e.g. in something like `join table2 on concat(table2.Year,'/',table2.Month,'%') like ...`); but you will have to set up the triggers (or however else you maintain the table), which is a little more complicated than just adding a fulltext index.